# Redirects http to https in ASP.NET 1.1

Tags: asp.net, .net, https

I wanted to redirect back a page with https, whenever requested with http.

I have used this code :

```
bool isSecure = false;
isSecure = Request.IsSecureConnection;

if(!isSecure)
{
    string redirectUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:");
    Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
}
```

Example of the pages are as below

Requested page :    http://google.com/test.aspx?id=12233

Redirects back to : https://google.com/test.aspx?id=12233

Currently it is pointing to the same : http://google.com/test.aspx?id=12233
and showing an error : Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

**The site where I am testing is not currently SSL certified..but my question is..Should not it be redirecting the page to https and then shows the error**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS default port is 443

If there is no service listening on your server on port 443, the redirect will fail immediatly. I guess the updating of the url in the address bar will be browser dependant.